# Finding out file encoding

Tags: utf-8, ms-word, character-encoding

I am having trouble finding out the file encoding of a file. It is the autocorrect list file (*.acl) of MS Office products. It consists of name/value pairs of mappings used to automatically substitute the `name` to `value`. I looked into it using a hex editor and found out following matchings.

```
Char - HEX   - Unicode Code Point - Unicode HEX repr.
a -    00 61 - U+0061             - 00 61 
A -    00 41 - U+0041             - 00 41
ä -    00 E4 - U+00E4             - C3 A4
© -    00 A9 - U+00A9             - C2 A9
```

The pattern I recognize is that the unicode code point is simply used to save the char in hex, instead of the correct hex value of the utf8 char. (I validated the schema of this list for ÄöÖüÜß and some other `[a-ZA-Z]` chars and it hold true for any of them. But I guess you don't need to see this to understand the pattern.)

Also the control characters `00 00 00 09` seems to be used as separation of the keys and values and `00 00 00 03` to separate the key/value pairs.

The motivation why I looked into this in the first place: I want to manipulate this file on my own using scripting. VBA is not an option. And I couldn't manage to input this file into my script correctly, yet. I hope you can help me  understanding the character encoding used.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Please consult the [help] about asking questions on Stack Overflow and what's on-topic. You could try asking this in Super User or on Microsoft Answers.

Comment: Microsoft hasn't published any documentation about the structure of acl files. You might find the discussion at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ccaf284b-2352-4be9-a34d-f227c4565c0f/what-is-the-structure-of-the-acl-files-that-are-used-in-the-autocorrect-function-of-microsoft-word?forum=word useful.

Comment: What you have shown is UTF-16 encoding, which seems to be confirmed by Peter Jamieson's post at 
February 28 2018 4:30 PM in the discussion that macropod linked to.  Try using codepoints above U+FFFF and this will be more apparent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes it is UTF-16. I think I get further from here. Thanks for the link and clarification.